# How to remove a urine smell from a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, smell

I have started noticing an unpleasant urine smell coming from my bathroom and initially thought it was someone living with me being careless with their streaming but later found out that the behind the toilet is ever so slightly leaking.

I will be calling out a plumber very soon but in the meantime I was wondering if anyone knew how to remove the odor of human urine?

Note that the floor is hard and non absorbent so no need to worry about washing things!

Comment: Every old folk's home everywhere would like a solution to this problem...but whatever they try, I can still smell it when I visit, usually overlaid with chemicals or fragrance. Seems impossible to remove from soft materials like carpet or bath mats unless they can be machine washed.

Comment: @Bamboo - My material is just like lino-ceramic type stuff so nothing soft to absorb the stuff

Comment: I reckon the smell will be better after the loo is fixed, but its possible contaminated water from the soil pipe has found its way beneath the lino where it joins around the toilet base, if its not sealed or stuck down. If possible, lift it up and check underneath - if its wet, let it dry and apply bleach, but not much point to this till the loo is fixed.

Comment: You should avoid using bleach to clean up urine because urine can contain ammonia. Mixing bleach and ammonia will create a toxic gas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to your local animal care facility and purchase any enzymatic based urine cleaner for dogs or cats. This works well on human urine stains too.

Answer (score 3):

First, if it's urine that is causing the stench, the urine smell may be neutralized by using a product called 20 Mule Team Borax. It can remove stains and fight the enzymes that cause that unpleasant smell. It won't be a waste of money because Borax has tons of other household uses too! I use Borax for issues similiar to the one you're having now, plus it works great as a laundry booster too! Check it out. Good Luck!!

Answer (score -1):

[Here are several ways](https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Urine-Smell). I've never used any of these, but they seem like good ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Use a sponge to scrub this onto the floor and the base of the toilet. Scrub the caulk and tile grout. Let it sit for a few minutes. Then spray with a 50/50 vinegar and water mixture.

Comment: Scrub "this" ?  Please expand your answer.

Comment: Scrub means rub

Comment: Welcome to lifehacks! This sounds promising, but do you have any sources to cite? Especially about the 50/50 mixture and _why_ it works. Thanks!